# Trouble parsing XML with namespaces using PHP SimpleXML Xpath

Tags: php, xpath, namespaces, simplexml

There are a few posts relating to PHP and SimpleXML with namespaces, but none of them see to address the challenge I'm having. Here is a small body of XML representative of a larger body that I'm having trouble with, nonetheless, the challenge is the same. I can't get any xpath queries to return the data I want. Observe the following

```
$xml = <<<EOD
<blah:book xmlns:chap="http://example.org/chapter-title" xmlns:blah="urn:blah">
    <blah:wrap>
        <chap:wrap>
            <title>My Book</title>
            <chapter id="1">
                <title>Chapter 1</title>
                <para>Donec velit. Nullam eget tellus vitae</para>
            </chapter>
            <chapter id="2">
                <title>Chapter 2</title>
                <para>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</para>
            </chapter>
        </chap:wrap>
    </blah:wrap>
</blah:book>
EOD;
```

The namespaces of "blah" and "chap" as they are in this first body don't seem to pose an problems. If I run the following php code with xpath query the following results:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$result = $sxe->xpath('/node()/*/*');
var_dump($result);

// gives me
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "My Book"
    ["chapter"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (3) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
        ["title"]=>
        string(9) "Chapter 1"
        ["para"]=>
        string(37) "Donec velit. Nullam eget tellus vitae"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (3) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(1) "2"
        }
        ["title"]=>
        string(9) "Chapter 2"
        ["para"]=>
        string(26) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem happens when "chap" is more prevalent such as this:

```
$xml = <<<EOD
<blah:book xmlns:chap="http://example.org/chapter-title" xmlns:blah="urn:blah">
    <blah:wrap>
        <chap:wrap>
            <chap:title>My Book</chap:title>
            <chap:chapter id="1">
                <chap:title>Chapter 1</chap:title>
                <chap:para>Donec velit. Nullam eget tellus vitae</chap:para>
            </chap:chapter>
            <chap:chapter id="2">
                <chap:title>Chapter 2</chap:title>
                <chap:para>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</chap:para>
            </chap:chapter>
        </chap:wrap>
    </blah:wrap>
</blah:book>
EOD;
```

After which, the same php code above results in this structure:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) {
  }
}
```

I've tried registering the namespace:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('chap', 'http://example.org/chapter-title');
$result = $sxe->xpath('/node()/*/*');
var_dump($result);
```

But still the same result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) {
  }
}
```

I've tried a number of different xpath queries none of which will return the entire body of xml in the array structure as shown above from the first body of xml. Here's a couple but I've tried wilder things out of desperation none of which worked.

```
$result = $sxe->xpath('/node()/chap:*/*');
$result = $sxe->xpath('/node()/*/chap:*');
```

Some posts have suggested removing all the namespaces and then not having to worry about it, but, there should be a way to parse it retrieve the whole body just as it's possible in the first example. Unfortunately I'm coming up empty-handed. I'll also admit, that I don't understand why the one occurrence of the 'chap' namespace in the first body doesn't cause a problem for the initial xpath query. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a possible solution is to use this as the xpath expression:

> $result = $sxe->xpath('//blah:book/blah:wrap');

[xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) returns an array from which you can take the first item. This will be of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) form which you can use the [children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method and pass the namespace.

You can loop the children in a foreach and the `$res` variable will be of type SimpleXMLElement. You can then check if the properties are set and get your data.

For example:

```
$xml = <<<EOD
<blah:book xmlns:chap="http://example.org/chapter-title" xmlns:blah="urn:blah">
    <blah:wrap>
        <chap:wrap>
            <chap:title>My Book</chap:title>
            <chap:chapter id="1">
                <chap:title>Chapter 1</chap:title>
                <chap:para>Donec velit. Nullam eget tellus vitae</chap:para>
            </chap:chapter>
            <chap:chapter id="2">
                <chap:title>Chapter 2</chap:title>
                <chap:para>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</chap:para>
            </chap:chapter>
        </chap:wrap>
    </blah:wrap>
</blah:book>
EOD;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$result = $sxe->xpath('//blah:book/blah:wrap');
foreach ($result[0]->children('http://example.org/chapter-title') as $res) {
    if (isset($res->title)) {
        $bookTitle = $res->title->__toString();
    }
    if (isset($res->chapter)) {
        foreach ($res->chapter as $chapter) {
            $chapterTitle = $chapter->title->__toString();
            $chapterPara = $chapter->para->__toString();
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/fMkjs)

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me. What I need is to be able to get everything back in a multi-dimensional array like I can without the namespaces. While this might enable me to end up with something similar after the foreaches, it requires that I know the element names before hand, and that's not quite how I want to approach this.